# 'unexpected quantifier' regexp error in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

I have a strings like `SHM{GHT}` and need to get a value from brackets (`GHT` in this example).
I use RegExp to get it and everything worked fine before I open it in IE. My page broke here and I got an error `unexpected quantifier`.

Here is my function

```
const getValueFromBrackets = (el): string => {
  const valueFromBrackets = el.match(/(?<=\{).+?(?=\})/g);
  return valueFromBrackets[0];
}
```

I checked on CanIUse `.match()` should work fine, something wrong with inside part `/(?<=\{).+?(?=\})/g`.
Any idea how can I rewrite it?

Would be really grateful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the lookbehind assertion `<=\{`, which is not supported in old engines. As a workaround, match `{(...)}` and take the first group:

```js
console.log('SHM{GHT}'.match(/{(.+)}/)[1])
```

Comment: @ifntuthnwh You can check the support for regex features via [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_lookbehind_assertion).